# Highlight lower numbered cell, if difference is 10 between two cells

Tags: excel

I have two columns of numbers. Say:

```
A1 is 80, B1 is 95
A2 is 50, B2 is 30
A3 is 20, B3 is 28
```

I want to do the following:

Highlight the lower number, if the difference between A1 & B1 is more than 10 .  So, in this case, I would want to highlight cell A1 & B2.

I need to do this for all rows. Hopefully this can be done without using VBA.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked in to Conditional Formatting? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I've tried conditional formatting. :) I'm stuck with identifying the “greater" number, as it's dynamic and can be in either column A or B. I've used =AND and =ABS formulas.